# In Jenkins how do you configure LDAP to restrict access to a specific group?

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, ldap, jenkins-plugins

I'm currently trying to setup a new install of Jenkins on a new VM to replace the old box in the corner server that currently runs. The old box was only ever configured with some basic users to share whereas the new box needs to correctly use the company's login system. I've managed to get it configured to such a point that LDAP works and users are able to login with their standard company username/password however it currently lets anyone log in (see image).

[image: LDAP Configuration]

What I need to do is restrict it to a specific group I have setup. The group is basically as below:

Group: `CN=IA-EC-DEV,OU=w2k,OU=group,OU=meplc,DC=users,DC=com`

Is there a way to modify the LDAP settings so that it only authenticates and allows users within this group to login?

```
Version Info:
Jenkins ver. 2.190.2
Active Directory plugin 2.16
LDAP Plugin 1.21
```

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory has a back-linked attribute, "memberOf". If all authorized users are directly a member of the group, use a filter like
`(&(cn={0})(memberOf=CN=IA-EC-DEV,OU=w2k,OU=group,OU=meplc,DC=users,DC=com))`

If you use nested groups (i.e. I'm a member of a group that is a member of a group that is a member of IA-EC-DEV and thus should be able to log into Jenkins), Active Directory has a special rule matching OID that handles ancestry. It is called [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/search-filter-syntax) and is used as `(&(cn={0})(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=IA-EC-DEV,OU=w2k,OU=group,OU=meplc,DC=users,DC=com))`

Comment: So is that replacing what i currently have in the user search filter or in one of the other fields?

Comment: Yes, the filter above replaces the current user search filter. Thus configuring Jenkins so it can only find accounts that are members of the group. It's backwards from the normal validate authentication, then check authorization flow but has the same effect -- you can log in if you are a member, cannot if you are not. If you need more than one group, use a compound filter like (&(cn={0})(|(memberOf=cn=group1,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com)(memberOf=cn=group2,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com)(memberOf=cn=group3,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com)))

Comment: No luck with that I'm afraid. I've tried many variations and tweaks but on test I'm always getting login denied. I did note, and I don't know if this is different, but when I set it up to work for all the LDAP Group membership groups listed do no include the one I'm trying to use. It shows a couple of groups called "team-project-users" and "team-project-admins". Are these things I should be trying to use maybe? If so how as anything I tried so far didn't work.